# How do I show all values in an aggregated tooltip?

Tags: altair

[image]

I would like myval to show the name of each car for each aggregated year, ex. "chevrolet chevelle malibu".

The [object Object] thing appears to be JavaScript related.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd
import pdb

df = data.cars()
alt.renderers.enable("altair_viewer")


mychart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .transform_joinaggregate(count="count(*)", myval="values(Name)", groupby=["Year"])
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "Year",
            timeUnit=alt.TimeUnitParams(unit="year", step=1),
            type="quantitative",
        ),
        y=alt.Y("count", type="quantitative"),
        tooltip=alt.Tooltip(["myval:N"]),
    )
)

mychart.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question, and I'm not sure there's a satisfactory answer. The reason this is displayed as `[object Object], [object Object]`, etc. is because the `values` aggregate returns a list of the *entire row* for each value. So the full representation would be something like this:

```
[{'Name': 'chevrolet chevelle malibu', 'Miles_per_Gallon': 18.0, 'Cylinders': 8, 'Displacement': 307.0, 'Horsepower': 130.0, 'Weight_in_lbs': 3504, 'Acceleration': 12.0, 'Year': 1970, 'Origin': 'USA'}, {'Name': 'buick skylark 320', 'Miles_per_Gallon': 15.0, 'Cylinders': 8, 'Displacement': 350.0, 'Horsepower': 165.0, 'Weight_in_lbs': 3693, 'Acceleration': 11.5, 'Year': 1970, 'Origin': 'USA'}, ...]
```

and those are just the first two entries! So clearly it won't really fit in a tooltip. For what it's worth, newer versions of Vega improve on this (which you can see by viewing the equivalent chart in the [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3OgENCCvCFIAnADYoQi5QHowC9ZQB0AK0rQQckAFtjAax0AjYyG6YokOiSSoQQggITWIABxQAbVBCAE8wzB0oCDsSBW1ueExNOh07WLR0mwBdbgAPVTiEnQBHUgUiOGViNETMrBydAE1Md25iO0wAVSgm1UpCTAjkAEZuUlHxZBBY3vUbW1jK+MTluobiZrhWjxAszuXIBfFZfvUGyhgIdTso0HMINIQEdUwEJV20RAEGmPGup3OuWWACpTgpKDorkQbJxQCCdIVNKRMAj2tkoSAAHIKQZwhHLfKYkrcH4UMIuLbISIgHruYrSdlAA)) but it's still not what you're looking for.

What you need is a way to extract just the name from each value in the list... and I'm sure that Vega-Lite transforms provide any good way to do that (the [vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) language does not have anything that resembles list comprehensions or function mapping).

The best I can think of is something like this, to display, say, the first 4 values:

[image]

```python
mychart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .transform_joinaggregate(count="count(*)", myval="values(Name)", groupby=["Year"])
    .transform_calculate(
        first_val="datum.myval[0].Name",
        second_val="datum.myval[1].Name",
        third_val="datum.myval[2].Name",
        fourth_val="datum.myval[3].Name",
      )
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "Year",
            timeUnit=alt.TimeUnitParams(unit="year", step=1),
            type="quantitative",
        ),
        y=alt.Y("count", type="quantitative"),
        tooltip=alt.Tooltip(["first_val:N", "second_val:N", "third_val:N", "fourth_val:N"]),
    )
)
```

Another option would be, instead of using a tooltip, to use a second chart that updates on mouseover:

[image]

```python
base = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .transform_joinaggregate(count="count(*)", values="values(Name)", groupby=["Year"])
)

selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Year'], on='mouseover', empty='none')

bars = (
    base    
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "Year:N",
            timeUnit=alt.TimeUnitParams(unit="year", step=1),
            type="quantitative",
        ),
        y=alt.Y("count", type="quantitative"),
    )
).add_selection(selection)

text = (
    base
    .transform_filter(selection)
    .transform_flatten(['values'])
    .transform_calculate(Name="datum.values.Name")
    .mark_text()
    .encode(
        y=alt.Y('Name:N', axis=None),
        text='Name:N'
    )
).properties(width=300)

chart2 = bars | text
```

I'd be interested to see if anyone knows of a more complete solution.